# 108-bit integer in test bench

Tags: c++, vivado, vivado-hls

I am using Vivado HLS 2018.3. I am defining 108-bit unsigned integer using `ap_int.h` library. In the test bench I am initializing a 108-bit variable as :

```
inData = 259614842926741381426524816461004;
```

However, while doing C simulation, I am getting error as follows :

```
warning: integer constant is too large for its type
```

And my code is not compiling. However this same source code works fine for 16-bit input in test bench.
Please suggest a way out. Thanks !

Comment: C or C++? Please pick only one target language, also see the descriptions of those tags. In any case, search for "large integer" plus the "[language]" in square brackets to find a bunch of related questions and to get an idea of possible approaches.

Comment: "using ap_int.h library." Okay, and *what does the documentation for the library say* about how to initialize the variables?

Comment: `this same source code works fine for 16-bit input` obviously. If you use `int` then it's required to have at least 16 bits by C and C++ standards. But there's no arbitrary-precision type in C or C++ and if the value is larger than `intmax_t` then you have to use bigint library

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't explain this question properly. It is not related to ordinary C/C++ but Vivado HLS. Vivado has some different rules regarding C/C++.